# Remove non-english words from dictionary in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dictionary, matrix

I have a dictionary that contains some words that have mistakes due to inconsistent formatting, for example the word 'directive' and 'directiveâ' and I would like to remove the second word which is both a duplicate and a non-english word. I have tried to use is letter but this method still returns true is it is an accented character. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I created the dictionary and its corresponding values matrix in TMG.

Okay so an example of the data would be for the corresponding values matrix:

> > X(1:20,1:10)
> >     ans =
> >     (17,3)        2
> >     (17,5)        2
> >     (17,7)        1
> >     (17,8)        2
> >     (17,10)       2 `

where the 17th word is present in the third document twice, the seventh document once etc.

`the dictionary:

> > bothWordsWithDocNumberDictionary(17:17,:)
> >     ans =
> >     able

My problem is that I have words present like sxusrvhvô°   or clusterâ, which are obviously undesirable.

Comment: Apologies for being thick but what is TMG? Post relevant snippets of your code, please....

Comment: Are you looking to remove any character not in the `[A-Za-z]` class? How about `é` (like Mrs Jones née Smith) . Please narrow down your problem statement. Is it "scrub for bad letters, then remove duplicates"?

Comment: HI! Thanks for your reply, yes I'm only looking for a-z/A-Z characters :) no accents or ascii characters etc. Thanks

Comment: @kkuilla TMG is a text matrix generator plug in for matlab, which takes text documents and outputs a dictionary of all words, and a corresponding matrix of 'word number (value,document)'.

Comment: I agree with @Floris. I think you need to make your question a bit more narrow. Could you post a few rows of your data, please. Show where the problem is and show what you want the correct output to be.

Comment: Okay so an example of the data would be 

for the corresponding values matrix:

`>> X(1:20,1:10)

ans =

  (17,3)        2
  (17,5)        2
  (17,7)        1
  (17,8)        2
  (17,10)       2`

where the 17th word is present in the third document twice, the seventh document once etc.

the dictionary:

`>> bothWordsWithDocNumberDictionary(17:17,:)

ans =

able  `

Comment: What?? I thought you were looking for text? Are these "offsets into a text document"? Or is your "word" literally the number 17? It would be better if you edited your question rather than include this information in a comment (where formatting is typically destroyed).

Comment: @CharlieMasters - it seems to me you have to very different problems. Let's break it into individual problems; adding the TMG format is complicating things but doesn't change the fundamental question. See if my `regexprep` solution solves the first part, then create a new question if you need help with a different part (related to the TMG format).

Comment: Apologies guys, see the edit above - might be a little more clear. I sill give the current suggested solution a go in the meantime, thanks!

Comment: Much clearer with the edits! What is the size of `bothWordsWithDocNumberDictionary`? It looks like it's a 2D character array, rather than a cell array - is that right? May I ask why?

Comment: its 13668x15 char - just how the TMG outputs it. 15 represents the maximum length of a word to be processed

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do two things:

First, go through the entire list and remove all "unallowed" characters. For example, if the only characters allowed are upper case and lower case `A-Z`, you could use the following expression to strip out any other characters:

```
newstring = regexprep(oldstring, '[^A-Za-z]', '', 'all');
```

This will find all characters that do NOT (`^`) fall in the character class identified. You can add other allowed characters like

```
newstring = regexprep(oldstring, '[^A-Za-zéè]', '', 'all');
```

if accented letter `é` is allowed.

Obviously you can go through a cell array of strings with either a `for` loop, or, if you feel up to it, by using `cellfun`. In the former case, you can either overwrite the old array, or create a new one. If you create a new one, make sure to preallocate space - it will make it much faster.  Example:

```
newstrings = cell(size(oldstrings));
for ii = 1:numel(oldstrings)
  newstrings{ii} = regexprep(oldstrings{ii}, '[^A-Za-z]', '', 'all');
end
```

Then you can remove duplicates from your cell array using

```
uniqueStrings = unique(newstrings);
```

That should do it for you. *disclaimer: was not able to test the above - let me know if you run into any problems*